# How to get font color of cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to get the font color of a cell in Google Sheets?

I have found a script for getting the colour of the background using `getBackground()`. However, I can't find anything for text colour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a function called [getFontColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontColor()).

Check the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) for more spreadsheet related references.

Answer (score 2):

**get this addon: [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/c](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count-and-sum/njiklelndjpdbdngfkdgeijcpfabfgkb?utm_source=permalink)**

and then you can use easy `IF` logic to get the color name:

```
=IF(COUNTFONTCOLOR("A1", "A1")=1, "red")
```

[image: 00]