# How to add cell and font color in app script code from google sheet to web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, background-color

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bheHs.jpg)Good morning,
i need a big help.
I am a beginner in programming.
I created a script that allows me to create a web app synchronized with the data that I put daily on my google sheet.

I would like that in addition to the data it also takes the color of the font and of the cell.

I think it's easier to understand from the pictures.

My Gs code

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}





function getData(){

  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Foglio1").getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
  const data=ss.map(v => {
return{
  "AUDIOLIBRI" : v[0]
}
  })
  data.shift()

  //console.log(data)

  return data
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.14"> </script>


</head>


<body>

  <div id="app">
  {{ message }}
<table class="w3-table-all">
  <thead>
<tr class="w3-light-grey">
  <th>Audible</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<template v-for="item in mydata" :key="item">
   <tr>
  <td>{{item.AUDIOLIBRI}}</td>
</tr>
  </template>

</table>

</div>


<?!= include('Vue'); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Vue.html

```
<script>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    message: 'Prova',
    mydata : [ ],

  },
  
    created: function () {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(this.onSuccess).getData();
  },

  methods:{
    onSuccess: function (serverData){
      this.mydata= serverData
    }
  }
})

</script>
```

i tried reading any post about it on stackoverflow and the official google guide but no concrete result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! You simply need to create a ```page.css``` that you include the same way as your ```Index.html```, and put some style in this file: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices?hl=fr#separate_html_css_and_javascript

Comment: Maybe I explained myself badly, sorry. I don't want to create my own style sheet (so do it) but pass to the web app both the data and the color of the cell and the font so that when I go to modify the google sheet it automatically copies me verbatim on the web app the my edits.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the background-color and font of Spreadsheet to your webapp, you should use a function like following but adapt it to your case.

You didn't put a lot a code, so I don't know how you handle exactly the data. Please consider this as a possibility among others

```
function getValueAndFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID); //to be completed
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME); // to be completed
  var max_row = sh.getLastRow();
  var arr = [];

  for (var x = 1; x <= max_row; x++) { //range start at 1

    var obj = {};
    obj.value = sh.getRange(x, 1).getValue(); // x is row number, 1 is column
    obj.bg_color = sh.getRange(x, 1).getBackground();
    obj.font = sh.getRange(x, 1).getFontFamily();

    arr.push(obj);
  }

  Logger.log(arr); //display the result
  // add your return, and handle the data client-side
}
```

**REFERENCES:**

- [Get Background](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=fr#getbackground)
- [Get Font Family](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=fr#getfontfamily)

**Other Sources :**

- [How to get font color of cell in Google Sheets? (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871901/how-to-get-font-color-of-cell-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but trying and trying again I still can't make the color appear. I edited the post again writing exactly all the code I wrote.
If you can look it up and give me some further help I would really appreciate it.